# Custom Post Type Search

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type, args

I'm building a custom post type search by post title. I have a post type 'produto' and two posts with the title 'Produto 1' and 'Produto teste 2'. The problem is when I put just 'f' in the search input the result is both posts instead of none.

I'm trying using the arg bellow but not success.

```
 $arg = array(
  'post_type' => 'produto',
          'search_prod_title' => '%'.$_POST['_searchvalue'].'%',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'orderby'     => 'title',
          'order'       => 'ASC'
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'search_prod_title'** is not allowed in the WordPress query. You can use either search parameter of [wp_query :](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter)

```
$args = array("post_type" => "mytype", "s" => $title);
$query = get_posts( $args );
```

Or you can get posts based on title throught [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

```
global $wpdb;
$myposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'", '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $title ) .'%') );
```

Comment: Thanks Faysal. I'll check this out.

Comment: Welcome, you should try this.